# Using lists in Pandas to replace column names

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand my mistake when using df.rename in pandas. Specifically, using the rename function with a tuple executes without error, but no changes are made to the column names.

```
f_GreaterArea = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), 
                index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h'],
                columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

print(f_GreaterArea)

    one       two     three
a  0.278969 -0.676388 -2.464444
c -0.992077 -0.435534  2.267315
e  2.094669 -1.401885  1.243658
f  0.886835  0.195726 -0.132382
h -0.920486 -0.298380  2.227378

old_colnames = ('one', 'two', 'three')
new_colnames = ('pig', 'cups', 'seven')


f_GreaterArea.rename(columns={old_colnames:new_colnames}, inplace=True)

print(f_GreaterArea)

    one       two     three
a  0.278969 -0.676388 -2.464444
c -0.992077 -0.435534  2.267315
e  2.094669 -1.401885  1.243658
f  0.886835  0.195726 -0.132382
h -0.920486 -0.298380  2.227378
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a tuple?

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to use were lists (and sparc_spread's answer allows this). The reason is that the lists are important later (e.g., specifying dropna columns, etc..)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are correct in wanting to pass in a `dict` with three entries, one for each column you are renaming, but the `dict` you are passing is not.  It's a `dict` of one entry, with one tuple as a key and one as a value.

Use a `dict` comprehension to turn the tuples into a `dict`, like this:

```
{i:j for i,j in zip(old_colnames,new_colnames)}
```

So in the context of your code, that's:

```
col_rename_dict = {i:j for i,j in zip(old_colnames,new_colnames)}
f_GreaterArea.rename(columns=col_rename_dict, inplace=True)
```

Or just:

```
f_GreaterArea.rename(
    columns={i:j for i,j in zip(old_colnames,new_colnames)}, inplace=True
)
```

Here's [a nice little write-up](https://www.smallsurething.com/list-dict-and-set-comprehensions-by-example/) on comprehensions in general, including the `dict` comprehension. It also includes usage of `zip`.

Comment: Glad to help & thanks for accepting!  Make sure to check out that link; comprehensions and zip are useful for all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

In python 3.8 and later you can simply assign the column names as a list

```
f_GreaterArea.columns = ['pig', 'cups', 'seven']
```

I know the question asks for a tuple, but from the comments it seems that the OP was trying to use a list.

Answer (score 2):

columns parameter should be this way:

```
{'one': 'pig', 'three': 'seven', 'two': 'cups'}
```

use this code to get it:

```
dict(zip(old_colnames, new_colnames))
```

If you want to change name of columns, use this code will be more easy:

```
f_GreaterArea.columns = ('pig', 'cups', 'seven')
```

Comment: I see how this technique works as well, and also uses the zip technique, as in sparc_spread's accepted answer.